# Why I can't smooth this curve by B-spline in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation, bspline

I check several different method, but why my curve can't be smoothed as what the others did? Here is my code and image.

```
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_x = [296, 297, 425, 460, 510, 532, 597, 601, 602, 611]
list_y = [2, 12, 67, 15, 21, 2037, 1995, 9, 39, 3]
bspl = splrep(list_x,list_y)
bspl_y = splev(list_x,bspl)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(list_x, bspl_y)   
plt.xticks(fontsize = 10)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the interpolation, because you give `matplotlib` the same 10 data points for the interpolated curve that you use for your original data presentation. We have to create a higher resolution curve:

```
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

list_x = [296, 297, 425, 460, 510,  521,  597, 601, 602, 611]
list_y = [2,   12,   67, 15,  21,  2037, 1995, 9, 39, 3]
bspl = splrep(list_x,list_y, s=0)
#values for the x axis
x_smooth = np.linspace(min(list_x), max(list_x), 1000)
#get y values from interpolated curve
bspl_y = splev(x_smooth, bspl)
plt.figure()
#original data points
plt.plot(list_x, list_y, 'rx-')
#and interpolated curve
plt.plot(x_smooth, bspl_y, 'b')   
plt.xticks(fontsize = 10)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 10)
plt.show()
```

And this is the output we get:
[image]